# Prevent getters/setters from generating for @Transient fields

Tags: annotations, javabeans, spring-roo

Spring Roo has an [@RooJavaBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/org.springframework.roo.annotations/apidocs/org/springframework/roo/addon/javabean/RooJavaBean.html) annotation which generates AspectJ getters and setters for non-transient fields. The problem is that it also generates them for transient fields. I have this in Asset.java:

```
@Transient
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
```

And I have the following in Asset_Roo_JavaBean.aj:

```
public Logger Asset.getLog() {
    return this.log;
}

public void Asset.setLog(Logger log) {
    this.log = log;
}
```

Even though a field is transient you should still be able to access it with getters and setters I suppose, but why do the docs say this for the `gettersByDefault` annotation field:

> whether to generate getters for each non-transient field declared in this class (defaults to true)

Is there another way I can prevent it from generating methods on transient fields so it treats them as private attributes?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Spring Roo are you using? According to the [ROO-3426 issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3426) JIRA entry the bug should be patched with version `1.2.5.RELEASE`.

1.) I would recommend upgrading your Roo, it should solve the problem.

2.) Be sure to check if imported `javax.persistence.Transient`.